# iframe wrapped in a hidden element incorrect scrollHeight

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I apologize that I cannot post actual code or a live working example. This problem requires an `iframe` so I cant just slap a fiddle together and the server this is deployed on is inaccessible from the net. Hopefully these snippets I will post are adequate for reproduction.

I have a page that needs to display another page in an `iframe` (I have no control over this) and the `iframe` should be sized according to the height of its content page which changes as the user interacts with it in various ways; the resizing is always due to hiding/showing elements, however, if that makes any difference.

This resize behavior works fine (in all browsers) with the exception of when the `iframe` wrapper is hidden initially. In this case the `iframe` is being sized to the size of what the target page *would be* if the `iframe` page elements were all visible in Chrome (so gigantic...), or invisible (0 height) in FF.

There are no JS errors in console and both pages have no problem accessing each other in other ways (`document.domain` is set). The page is `XHTML Transitional`, but I should be able to change this if it makes a difference.

iframe HTML:

```
<div id="frame-wrapper" style="display: none">
    <iframe src="some_page_that_shrinks_after_dom_load.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="javascript:frameLoaded(this);"></iframe>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
function frameLoaded(iframe) {
    function resizeIframe() {
        iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
        alert(iframe.style.height);
    }

    // ...
    // set up some callbacks in the iframe to resizeIframe() which do work and give correct size, probably because the wrapper is unhidden
    // ...

    // this call for the size at the time of load is what is broken iff "frame-wrapper" is display: none
    resizeIframe();
    // the hack im using to avoid this:
    $('#frame-wrapper').show();
    resizeIframe();
    $('#frame-wrapper').hide();
}
```

As you can see I already know how to hack around the problem. What I would really like is an explanation of what is going on here.

Comment: Have you tried running `setTimeout(resizeIframe, 100);`? Of course, you would need to save the reference to the `iframe` within `frameLoaded()`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish can you elaborate on how that might be relevant to what is happening? I don't need a workaround (I have one) i'm looking for an explaination of why my workaround is required.

Comment: @JaredFarrish regardless, `setTimeout` doesnt work either :/